# How to select all rows where ManyToMany relationship is empty or null

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two classes

```
@Entity
public class Program {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name = "program_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
      private Set<ProgramRole> programRoles;

}

@Entity
public class ProgramRole {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
}
```

I would like to write JPA query for selecting all Programs where `programRoles` is empty or null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `JpaRepository` of `Program, Long` to achieve your requirement.
The following should work:

```
@Repository
public interface ProgramRepository extends JpaRepository<Program, Long> {
        List<Program> findByProgramRolesIsEmpty();
    }
```

This method will return all Program entities with an empty `Set<ProgramRole>` which at least is true for empty or null `Set`